# Customise the prompt and display the Battery Capacity?

Tags: command-line, prompt, zsh

How do I customise the zsh-Prompt to show for example the time, the wi-fi status and the Battery Capacity?

Is it possible to see my current battery charge in the prompt? I have only found a way how to do that on mac os.

Answer (score 1):

These are the commands I know to check system status from command-line:

**For time:** `date`

**For wi-fi:** `iwconfig` or `ifconfig`

**For battery:** `acpi` or `acpi -b`- more info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface), also you may need to install it first.

*For more info on each command, run:*

`man acpi`

`man date`

`man ifconfig`

`man iwconfig`